# How can I count the number of files containing a specific string but not containing another string?

Tags: bash

We run daily Selenium tests to test our website and extensions. If the test fails, the output contains the string FAILED (it doesn't matter if it contains other strings). If it passes, the output doesn't contain the string FAILED but must contain the string OK. If the output doesn't contain both strings (usually when it's empty), the test failed. Our code for counting the tests which failed is like this:

```
today=`TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
yesterday=`TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday"`

print_test_results()
{
    log_suffix="_${file_name}.log"
    yesterday_logs="${log_prefix}${yesterday}_[1,2]*${log_suffix}"
    today_logs="${log_prefix}${today}_0*${log_suffix}"
    passed_tests=`fgrep -L FAILED $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null`
    failed_tests=`fgrep -l FAILED $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null`
    total_tests=`ls -1 $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null`
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>$test_name - $today</td>"
    if [ $passed_tests = "0" ]; then
        echo "<td>$passed_tests passed</td>"
        echo "<td><span style=\"color: red;\">$failed_tests failed</span></td>"
    else
        echo "<td><span style=\"color: green;\">$passed_tests passed</span></td>"
        echo "<td>$failed_tests failed</td>"
    fi
    echo "<td>$total_tests tests total</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
}
```

But the problem is, it ignores the OK string if both strings are not in the output (for example when the file is empty), it counts a passed test. How can we count passed tests and failed tests correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the files and perform a proper check.  Searching the string will outweigh any overhead created by the shell counting.

```
declare -i fail=0
declare -i success=0

for fileName in *
do
  if grep -q FAILED "$fileName"
  then
    fail+=1
  elif grep -q OK "$fileName"
  then
    success+=1
  else
    fail+=1
  fi
done

printf "%d failed, %d succeeded\n" "$fail" "$success"
```

A different approach would be to pass file name lists.  Count how many files in which `FAILED` does *not* occur, have `OK` in them:

```
grep -l OK $(grep -L FAILED *) | wc -l
```

Count how many files have `FAILED` in them or *neither* `FAILED` *nor* `OK`:

```
(grep -l FAILED *; egrep -L 'FAILED|OK' *) | wc -l
```

The counting approach will have problems with strange file names (i. e. whitespace or newlines in the file names etc.), but probably you can safely assume that in your special case the file name are decently.

Comment: It worked! I used the first approach since the lines are shorter, but probably both of them work. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901741/how-do-i-redirect-errors-to-dev-null-in-bash for error messages caused by this script.